# Why do both tf.nn.relu and tf.nn.sigmoid work the same in this custom estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, activation-function, sigmoid, relu

This is the guide to make a custom estimator in TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators

The hidden layers are made using `tf.nn.relu`:

```
# Build the hidden layers, sized according to the 'hidden_units' param.
for units in params['hidden_units']:
    net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

I altered the example a bit to learn **XOR**, with `hidden_units=[4]` and `n_classes=2`. When the activation function is changed to `tf.nn.sigmoid`, the example works as usual. **Why is it so? Is it still giving correct result because XOR inputs are just zeros and ones?**

Both functions give smooth loss curves converge to zero line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About XOR problem, `relu` solved a vanishing gradient that an error value by back propagation is vanished in deep hidden layers.

So, `Sigmoid` works if you make just one hidden layer.

[image]

Sigmoid has a vlue in 0~1.
An Error value by back propagation from output layer is going to be very small value at the far from output layer by a partial differential equation.

[image]

Blue line is Relu and Yellow line is Sigmoid.

Relu has x value if it is over than 0.
So, Error value can be reached to 1st layer.

Comment: tks, is relu a must if using more than 1 hidden layer?

Comment: @datdinhquoc   yes. not just 1.  But, Relu is ok for 1 hidden layer too. So, I recommend relu for hidden layer.  There are various activation functions.  Basically, It's depends on your model.  In example, For the binary classification of NN, You need to use sigmoid for output layer.